# Extracting excel cells - beginner

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I am a newbie trying to write a script to extract info from a spreadsheet and present it as a report in Libre office writer using autopygui and openpyxl. My try:

```
from subprocess import call
import openpyxl, pyautogui

call("libreoffice")
calcfile = "calcexample.xlsx"

pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab') # focus on Writer
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(calcfile) # open xml file
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') # open sheet X, to print specific cells
print = ("Reading calc file...")

# trying to write cells as text in the doc
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    for col in range (2, 6):
        pyautogui.typewrite(sheet[col, row].value)
        pyautogui.typewrite('enter')
```

I get this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "a.output.py", line 30, in
> <module><br>
>     pyautogui.typewrite(sheet[col, str(row)].value)   File "/home/m/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py",
> line 354, in __getitem__<br>
>     min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)   File "/home/m/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py",<br>
> line 127, in range_boundaries<br>
>     m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object<br>
> m@m-SATELLITE-C855-2CQ:~/python-stuff/projects/04-Asistente
> corrección$ python3 a.output.py Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "a.output.py", line 30, in <module><br>
>     pyautogui.typewrite(sheet[str(col), str(row)].value)   File "/home/m/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py",
> line 354, in __getitem__<br>
>     min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)   File "/home/m/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/utils/cell.py",
> line 127, in range_boundaries<br>
>     m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string) <br> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object<br>
```

Which I think is due to the format of "col" and "row". I tried using str() with no results. I know I am missing something quite basic here, but couldn't figure out what. My questions:

1. How to deal with the error message.
2. Is it ok to read-write directly from file or it will be more efficient/elegant to append values to a dictionary and get them from there?

Comment: "How to deal with the error message." by looking at (and letting us look at) the full error message with the traceback. It's not clear where this error happened.

Comment: I just added the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are not meant to be accessed as `sheet[col, row]`. Why did you assume that? As the [tutorial](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html#playing-with-data) says, use a single string specifying the location:

```
sheet['A4']
```

or use the `cell` method:

```
sheet.cell(row=row, column=col)
```